# Maven - Have an XSD as a dependency

Tags: maven-2, xsd

We have one project that defines the message formats it produces with XSD files.

What is the easiest way to make these XSD files as dependencies of another project?

I was looking at using the [maven-build-helper attach-artifact](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/attach-artifact-mojo.html) goal to attach my XSD files.

Is there a better mechanism?

Comment: Do you want the project packaging type to be xsd as opposed to jar or pom?

Comment: the attach-artifact goal is as good as it gets. Every other solution would do the same thing in a more complicated way :-)

Answer (score 5):

I don't know the attach-artifact goal but I did something like you asked for. I had wsdl and xsd files to write Webservice artifacts and its client artifacts with axis2.

1. I put my wsdl and xsd in an own
   project named 'wsdl' to
   src/main/resources/META-INF and
   nothing else.
2. I made a own project
   named 'soap' for the generated
   Java-SOAP-Code. In this project I
   added the the wsdl project as
   dependency and unpacked the wsdl and
   xsd files via
   maven-dependency-plugin to the
   target folder in the
   initialize-phase. So I can use it to
   generate the SOAP-Code.
3. The soap
   project I used as dependency for the
   Webservice project and for the
   client project.

I put all these projects to a multi module project so that I can build all together.
I think the important part for you is the configuration of dependency-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>unpack-wsdl-dependency</id>
        <phase>initialize</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>unpack</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <artifactItems>
        <artifactItem>
          <groupId>${groupId}</groupId>
          <artifactId>wsdl</artifactId>
          <outputDirectory>target/wsdl</outputDirectory>
          <includes>META-INF/*.wsdl,META-INF/*.xsd</includes>
        </artifactItem>
      </artifactItems>
      <!-- other configurations here -->
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Hope that helps.

Greetings Michael